# Python3 GUI script does not work when double clicked

Tags: linux, python-3.x, ide, pyqt5, linux-mint

My GUI script that is a PyQt5 file (.pyw extension) does work when running on my IDE with a build configuration that tells the compiler to run the script with python3:

[image]

And it also works when i tell to the regular terminal on Linux to run same script with python3 like this:

[image]

When runned with the default python (python2.7) on a regular terminal it tells: `ImportError: No module named PyQt5.QtWidgets`.

My code does it have these lines on the start to tell that is a python3 script like: `#!/usr/bin/python3` or `#!/usr/bin/env python3` (I have python3 installed).

When double clicked on the Linux Mint File Explorer the cursor turns crosshair and nothing happends, with the terminal option, same happends and a empty terminal shows. Im talking these options

[image]

I guess Linux Mint still runs the scripts with python2.7 even when I added the bash lines to tell

Someone knows why the lines:

- `#!/usr/bin/python3`
- `#!/usr/bin/env python3`

doesnt work when just double click?

I want to run the script from the Linux File Explorer without the need of an IDE or using the terminal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try chmod +x file.py and run it in terminal by using ./file.py also try lunching the file from a different path, like python3 ~/path/to/file.py and see if the error persists

Comment: Running on terminal with python3 works as I stated before, the chmod +x /test.py command worked and I tried with other ones without the chmod line and they worked perfectly. I dont know what happend here

Comment: Python can be difficult to run when not ran from an IDE, is your problem solved ?

Comment: Yes it is thanks. But as I said, I dont know why other python3 files worked without using the chmod line. Its like the chmod repaired a lot more stuff.